# Zip files and read path from text file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a text file and it contains the path with filename and I want to zip all the files in this text file into one zip file.
Can someone help me please?

I already tried this

```
cat log.txt | zip -@ - > zipfile.zip
```

Comment: What is the problem though?

Comment: What happens when you do that?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

What you have works on my system. Though a slightly more idiomatic linux line might be:

```
zip -@ zipfile.zip < log.txt
```